# Detach All Packages Imported by Another Package in R

Tags: r, package, detach

So, I'm trying to use the package "ecp," but loading it throws the following error:

```
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
  namespace ‘Rcpp’ is imported by ‘tibble’, ‘htmltools’, ‘purrr’, 
‘scales’, ‘plyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘tidyr’ so cannot be unloaded
Error in library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, 
lib.loc = lib.loc,  : 
  Package ‘Rcpp’ version 0.12.8 cannot be unloaded
```

The packages it's referring to were imported when I loaded the package "plotly." Using `detach('package:plotly', unload=TRUE)` does not fix the error, I presume because it doesn't unload the rest of the packages that plotly brought with it. Is there a fast way to unload both a package and all the packages it imports, or does one have to go through them all manually in situations like this?

Comment: Just refer to functions in `ecp` you need with `ecp::function_name()`; you don't need to load it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i need to detach particular package will use the below code :

```
detach("package:data.table")
```

but wants to detach all the packages (base packages will available by default)

```
lapply(paste('package:',names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs),sep=""),detach,character.only=TRUE,unload=TRUE)
```